# How can I pass arguments to ranlib using cmake?

Tags: cmake, static-linking

How can I pass an argument to `ranlib` when compiling a static library with CMake?

I tried:

```
set_target_properties(myLibrary STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS "--plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/liblto_plugin.so")
```

and this worked for `ar` but not for the subsequent `ranlib` command.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
SET(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_FINISH   "<CMAKE_RANLIB> -no_warning_for_no_symbols -c <TARGET>")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_FINISH "<CMAKE_RANLIB> -no_warning_for_no_symbols -c <TARGET>")
```

On the Mac, this is how I pass the "-no_warning_for_no_symbols" flag to ranlib.

Note:  The SET commands don't modify the *ranlib* command used as part of an installation by running "make install."  CMake's installer code does not generate installation scripts that allow for options to be added to *ranlib.*

Answer (score 1):

For CMake 3.13+, use `STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS`:

```
set_property(
    TARGET myLibrary
    APPEND
    PROPERTY STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS "-no_warning_for_no_symbols"
)
```

For older versions of CMake, use `STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS`:

```
set_property(
    TARGET myLibrary
    APPEND
    PROPERTY STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS "-no_warning_for_no_symbols"
)
```

Comment: this did not work for me

Comment: Since CMake 3.13, there is STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS. I modified my answer to reflect this.