# What does "library has no symbol" mean?

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake, linker

I'm using CMake to build some dependency libraries that are required for my projects. They are Boost_system, Boost_filesystem, and Boost_program_options. I'm compiling the static libraries separately, rather than to compile the whole Boost library.

Everything works, but I got the following warning messages:

```
...
[ 67%] Building CXX object filesystem/CMakeFiles/filesystem.dir/src/utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object filesystem/CMakeFiles/filesystem.dir/src/windows_file_codecvt.cpp.o
[ 74%] Linking CXX static library libfilesystem.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libfilesystem.a(windows_file_codecvt.cpp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libfilesystem.a(windows_file_codecvt.cpp.o) has no symbols
[ 74%] Built target filesystem
[ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/canalogsmp.dir/src/Array2D.cpp.o
...
```

My question would be:

- What is the symbol? And what does the warning message mean?
- How can I get rid of this warning message?

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to close this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [nakiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466694/nakiya), I have found the answer.

So the explanation for the warning message is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929255/building-static-libraries-on-mac-using-cmake-and-gcc#answer-4953904). Basically, there is no operational code found by `ranlib`. But in my case, I just need to ignore the warnings.

Solution for that is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319369/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-ranlib-using-cmake#answer-33067038), also pasted below. Make sure that you pass the flags to `ranlib` rather than the compiler per se.

```
SET(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_FINISH   "<CMAKE_RANLIB> -no_warning_for_no_symbols -c <TARGET>")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_FINISH "<CMAKE_RANLIB> -no_warning_for_no_symbols -c <TARGET>")
```

Comment: Please repeat the explanation and solution here, rather than just linking.

Comment: add it here so I can upvote the answer. If those links die this is useless